# UIWebView Delegates Not Triggering ? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, delegates

I am loading a local HTML into a UIWebView as follows :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Setup our UIWebView
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
webView.delegate = self;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
...
[self loadWebPage];
}

- (void)loadWebPage {

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
 }
```

And in the header :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

However for some reason my webview delegates are not being called :

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
NSLog(@"Starting HTML Load Process");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViewRef {
NSLog(@"Web View Finished Loading Method");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Error loading HTML ! %@", error);
}
```

Can anyone suggest why ?

Thanks !

Comment: The method is defined as `-(void)loadWebPage` but called `[self loadWeb];`. I presume this is a typo when posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Called the method [self loadWeb];

But on definition the method is  - (void)loadWebPage;

Is it typo?

Answer (score 0):

how did you declare your `UIWebView` instance variable, as a strong or weak? If weak make it strong.

Comment: if webview is declared as weak then its scope is only limited to the viewdidload. But the request is getting fired in loadWebPage.

Comment: @Popeye please see my above comment and let me know whether I am right or not?As per my understanding it will solve the problem.

Comment: Simple this doesn't answer the question in any way. Recheck the code and read it and you will see that he is calling `[self loadWeb]` and the method is declared as `- (void)loadWebPage;` so they need to be calling `[self loadWebPage];` this has nothing to do with whether it is declared `strong` or `weak`. That is the reason I have downvoted. **Edit** They have changed there code now, I will remove my -1 but based on when you answered this question it would have been completely incorrect.

Comment: @Popeye that was the typo by the user.Also if user is calling [self loadWeb] but loadWeb not declare and define in .h/.m then he would certainly get an error/warning at compile time.

Comment: Ever way you answer the question before the user had said that was a typo so it was a valid downvote. Like I have said I have removed my -1 because of the user editing the question.

Comment: @Popeye Agreed with you that might the cause and thanks for your courtesy.I would be more conscious while posting any solution.

Comment: We all do it. I did it with the comment, it just that comments don't get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can reproduce is this by declaring the `webView` @property as weak. Can you confirm you are declaring it as a strong reference?

Comment: It's declared as strong

Comment: @Ohnomycoco please include this in the question then, we need to know all the information to make a good a most accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this call.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]];
```

Looks like you're loading the HTML from inside your bundle. This means you need to confirm that all the additional files `(.js, .css, and any media files)` also need to be present in your bundle.

So the first thing need to check `fileURLWithPath`: point either it's returning nil or not. If it's not then it means that .html page resolved, however the additional files not resolved as part of the request because it's not placed on the same "index.html" path.

First you need to confirm the directory structure of your "index.html" and all the additional files used inside the page. In order to do that, you have to right click on binary .app in your "build" directory in the finder and then select "Show Package contents".

**binary (.app) > right click > Show Package contents**

This shows what the app's main bundle contains. Look inside for your HTML file. If it's in a folder, that folder name needs to be in the `inDirectory` parameter of the `pathForResource` call. If it's on the top-level then you don't have a folder reference. Either delete & re-drag it into project or use the `pathForResource` version without `inDirectory`.

The best way to don't setup the base path or relative path for the resources inside .html page (.js, .css and images) because it don't work. Copy all the additional resources next to "index.html" file so it would be easy to resolve on runtime from bundle.

```
NSString *path = @"<Index.html Path>";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [path lastPathComponent] 
             relativeToURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] 
                                       isDirectory: YES]];
```

Comment: An exception would be thrown by `fileURLWithPath:` if the file is not in the bundle as `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]` would return nil.

Comment: That's true. He haven't mentioned about the exception which means the requested file resolved but some of the additional resources inside the "index.html" file could have not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO];
```